# PHP Shell_exec isn't capturing the full output/is not waiting for the command to finish

Tags: php, praat

I'm trying to call a Praat script from the command line using PHP (shell_exec command).

However, it appears that it isn't waiting for the script to finish before it returns. For example, when my "hello world" script is called, $output_string only contains "h".

$command_string runs perfectly when copy-pasted into the terminal directly. When var_dump($output_string) is run, it correctly shows the required output, however error_log still only prints "h"

an attempt at a minimally reproducible example:

Praat script:

```
writeInfoLine:"hello world"
```

PHP code:

```
$output_string = shell_exec("\"path_to_praat.exe\" --run \"path_to_script\"");
error_log($output_string);
```

Comment: What you get when doing `var_dump($output_string)`. Also you are missing semicolons. Is it only in question or in code too?

Comment: Can you include a [mcve]?

Comment: @Justinas var_dump correctly outputs what should've been printed!! How do I take that info from var_dump to use in my code? semicolons are missing here only - I'll add that in.

Comment: The issue you're facing with shell_exec not waiting for the Praat script to finish might be due to a few reasons, such as buffering or the execution time limit. try adding ob_flush(); flush(); to clear cache, and also try increasing execution time.

Comment: @hweh If `var_dump` shows correct output, means `$output_string` has what it needs to have. Use it in code.

Comment: I've never seen `$output_string = shell_exec("path_to_praat.exe" --run "path_to_script");` would be valid PHP code.

Comment: `don't know how to mark a thread as done` post your answer and then once SO allows (IIRC 24hrs) accept your own answer as solution and rollback your last edit to the question. That's perfectly fine here.

Comment: sorry as you can tell I'm very new to stack overflow - I'm now facing an issue where in spite of var_dump showing that $output_string contains data, string methods (e.g. strpos() ) are not working as they should on it. Should i close this thread and start a new one? or do I keep searching for help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shell_exec() was returning the correct output. However, the way that Praat was outputting text was incompatible with how PHP was processing it.

I found out that the text was being weird when I converted it to json, and effectively saw "\u0000h\u0000e\u0000l\u0000l\u00000o ...." printed out.

Once I cleaned $output string with

```
$output_string = str_replace("\0", "", $output_string);
```

Everything worked perfectly